# How to test Gibbon with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, mailchimp, gibbon

I want to do a test whether a user has successfully subcribed after signing up in the newsletter form in my application.

I found this similar question [Testing Mailchimp 3.0 and Gibbon 2.x with Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528415/testing-mailchimp-3-0-and-gibbon-2-x-with-rspec) and no one responded.

I have a solution in mind, and that is using the methods from gibbon like `gibbon.lists(list_id).members.retrieve` and check if the user exist in the resulting object.

Comment: Experiencing this now. Any progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details of MailChimp, but in general, your app would either **poll MailChimp's API** for new subscribers, or MailChimp would **ping your app's endpoint** to notify about it.

In any case, you'd probably want to use something like https://github.com/vcr/vcr to *record* the MailChimp's response and test against that.

**In the first case (polling)**

your test would call a method like

`MailChimpFacade.new_subscribers_since(last_time_you_checked_for_subscribers)`

And you can mock that method, to return data (one subscriber, zero subscribers, many subscribers).

**In the second case (ping)**

when MailChimp sends a request to one of your controllers - use such VCR payload and send it to the controller to test it.

That's a general idea.

There are also other considerations: what should happen when MailChimp is unavailable when it returns gibberish etc. - you may want to test against it using the techniques described above as well.